# How to div short - Java

Tags: java, javacard

I need to divide by 2 the short word, for example 0x40 (in dec: 64 ) to 0x20 (in dec: 32). I cannot use int (java card) - only short.

Someone have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

How about...

```
short myShort = (short) 0x40;
myShort >>= 1;
```

Where the shift right operator is used to perform integer division by 2.

Comment: You got in there just as I was typing in my identical answer!  ;^)  +1 to you!

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is divide a short by 2 then I'd use a bit shift operator. as in

```
    short a = 8;
    a >>= 1;                  // Shift by one bit is the same as divide by 2
    System.out.println(a);
```